# How to make a snowboard (or squeezed rectangle) shaped div in css?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I am trying to get this shape:
[image]
So far I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/4kekbhey/). Is there a way to get this effect using CSS? I thought a negative radius would probably work.

```css
div {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    min-width: 200px;
    border-radius:10% / 70%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
    Board
</div>
```

Comment: You just need to apply a huge-radius "eraser" on top and at the bottom of it.

Comment: Any way to achieve this without white blobs? I have a background image

Comment: No really. I mean not with CSS only. You can always place the "eraser" background on top of it.

Comment: There is an ultra-complex way using gradients to do it without the white areas but not worth the effort, it will require a lot of effort to write one and then make it fit all browsers etc. So, if the background is not a plain color, I wouldn't suggest CSS.

Comment: The gradient method would resemble (not same but similar) Mikhail's answer in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26196460/how-to-pinch-the-middle-of-a-line-in-css).

Comment: You can use pseudo-elements with `box-shadows` and main element with `overflow: hidden;` This allows the upper and lower parts to be transparent. http://jsfiddle.net/w0nyb9wv/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I like stuff like this as I always mess around to create things like this.  So here is how I would do it. Using `:before` and `:after` we can create this shape, we use them to create a shape to sit on top of the `div` with the same colour as the background. This will make it look like the shape you want.

Make the `:before` and `:after` big and smaller to get the size you want (change the width and height).

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  min-width: 200px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}
div:before,
div:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 96%;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
}
div:before {
  top: -17px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
div:after {
  bottom: -17px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>Board</div>
```

Comment: @user3801433 That should have been changed I forgot to do it, that is not needed for this to work. I have fixed it now.

Comment: @user3801433 border-radius: 10% / 70%; is for making ovals. 10% is one side, 70% is the other side

Comment: @Ruddy Any way to achieve this without white blobs? I have a non-single colour background

Comment: +1 You beat me to it, and your board looks nicer! :)

Comment: @andrew Off the top of my head I can't think of another way. I will have a mess around when I get a chance and see if I can create it without the blobs.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comment, you need to chop off some wood from the top and the bottom of the board. @Ruddy's board looks much better though.

I used those super-high radius values because of the way they're actualy measured on boards and skis. Using snowboard specs , you could actually achieve the identical look/shape.

That's about as far as you can get with plain CSS (with tweaking the numbers, of course).

But if you need it to be a semi-transparent object to be put over a (colorful) background so that you can't use the white eraser, you'd be better off using a HTML canvas and a simple JS.

```css
div {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    min-width: 200px;
    border-radius:10% / 70%;
    background-color: red;
}
div:before, div:after {
  content: "";
  background-color: white;
  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 800px;
  position: absolute;
  }
div:before {
  margin: -804px 0 0 -307px;
}
div:after {
  margin: 4px 0 0 -307px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    Board
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#a{position:relative;height:50px;width:100px;background-color:green;border-radius:50%;}
#b{position:relative;top:-48px;left:50px;height:46px;width:100px;background-color:green;}
#c{position:relative;top:-96px;left:100px;height:50px;width:100px;background-color:green;border-radius:50%;}
```

```html
<div id="a"></div><div id="b"></div><div id="c"></div>
```

Comment: That's a weird looking snowboard :P

Comment: Admitted, Never used one, the one above looks better? Bet mine sticks to the snow better though

Comment: Haha, this is a skimboard, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

```css
#board-cont{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#board-cont .board{
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 190px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius:15% / 70%;
    background-color: red;
}
#board-cont .border-top{
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    border-top: 3.4482758620689653px solid #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 3.4482758620689653px solid #ffffff;
    border-left: 100px solid #ffffff;
    border-right: 100px solid #ffffff;
    border-radius: 100px / 3.4482758620689653px;
    left: 0px;
    top: -4px;
}
#board-cont .border-bottom{
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    border-top: 3.4482758620689653px solid #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 3.4482758620689653px solid #ffffff;
    border-left: 100px solid #ffffff;
    border-right: 100px solid #ffffff;
    border-radius: 100px / 3.4482758620689653px;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="board-cont">
    <div class="border-top"></div>
    <div class="border-bottom"></div>
    <div class="board"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Achieving this in CSS would be a lengthy process. You could use an SVG instead:

```html
<svg height="150" width="500">
<ellipse style="fill:lime" ry="50" rx="109" cy="49" cx="220" />
<ellipse style="fill:white" ry="73" rx="270" cy="-51" cx="214" />
<ellipse style="fill:white" ry="73" rx="270" cy="151" cx="214" />
</svg>
```